# Remove tags and url from img string

Tags: php, image, preg-replace

I user the CK Editor and want to separate all the image contents when posting.
The string is like this when posting:

```
$string1 = '<h1>Foo bar!</h1> <img src="foo.bar/image.jpg" />';
$string2 = '<p>Hello world</p><br><img src="another.url/image123.jpg" />'
```

**Find images**

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$string1, $result1);
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$string2, $result2);
```

**How can I translate the...**

```
<img src="foo.bar/image.jpg" />
```

**To:**
image.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this code

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<img src="another.url/image123.jpg" />');
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
        echo basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));
    }
?>
```

Comment: OP needs just the filename , so you should use `basename()`

Comment: It should be `echo basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));` because this is what OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=".+?([^"\/]+)\"[^>]+>/i',$string1, $result1);
```